# C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

when I use CMake to generate projects in visual studio and build it, I met the problem as the title says. 
In the Cmake I have integrated QT libraries. See the following lines:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${TOOLS_SOURCE_DIR}/../extern/qt5/include
  ${TOOLS_SOURCE_DIR}/../extern/qt5/include/QtCore
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Generated_Files
)

SET(GPS_TRANSFORMER_SRC
  GPSTransformerNode.cxx
)
SET(GPS_TRANSFORMER_MOC_H
  GPSTransformerNode.h
)
SET(GPS_TRANSFORMER_UI
)

QT_WRAP_CPP(GPS_TRANSFORMER_MOC_CXX ${GPS_TRANSFORMER_MOC_H})
QT_WRAP_UI(GPS_TRANSFORMER_UI_H ${GPS_TRANSFORMER_UI})
SOURCE_GROUP("Generated Files" FILES ${GPS_TRANSFORMER_MOC_CXX} ${GPS_TRANSFORMER_UI_H})
```

In visual studio, after building it,it comes to this error. Following are details.

```
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "RosGpsTransformer.dir\Release\RosGpsTransformer.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "RosGpsTransformer.dir\Release\RosGpsTransformer.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>CustomBuild:
1>  Building Custom Rule E:/Projects/MyRosPacage/NODES/src/RosGpsTransformer/CMakeLists.txt
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because E:\Projects\MyRosPacage\NODES\win32\RosGpsTransformer\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  Generating Generated_Files/moc_GPSTransformerNode.cxx
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Then I noticed that in the project there is a folder called "Generated Files" and a file called "moc_GPSTransformerNode.cxx" in it. When I try to click on it, it cannot be open.

Does anybody know how I solve this problem?

Comment: The most logical conclusion is that you forgot to *create* the "Generated Files" directory.

Comment: ***"moc_GPSTransformerNode.cxx" in it. When I try to click on it, it cannot be open.*** Problem with your antivirus software? Wrong Permissions? I would investigate why you can't open this file since this would likely cause a build failure.

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained clearly. The "moc_GPSTransformerNode.cxx" exists in the "Solution Explorer" list in the folder "Generated Files". When i click it , it says "The document cannot be opened, It has been renamed, removed or deleted ". Then I go to E: drive where the project exists, the folder 'Generated Files" exists but nothing is inside.